# How can I get iso code and name from ruby Money::Currency.all in ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I get iso code and name from Money::Currency.all in Ruby

How can I get iso code and name from Money::Currency.table in Ruby

Money::Currency.all is Array ,I used map ,but don't work

Money::Currency.table is Hash ,I have not find one method to handle the problem

this is Money::Currency.all

```
{
            "id": "usd",
            "alternate_symbols": [
                "US$"
            ],
            "decimal_mark": ".",
            "disambiguate_symbol": "US$",
            "html_entity": "$",
            "iso_code": "USD",
            "iso_numeric": "840",
            "name": "United States Dollar",
            "priority": 1,
            "smallest_denomination": 1,
            "subunit": "Cent",
            "subunit_to_unit": 100,
            "symbol": "$",
            "symbol_first": true,
            "thousands_separator": ","
        },
        {
            "id": "eur",
            "alternate_symbols": [],
            "decimal_mark": ",",
            "disambiguate_symbol": null,
            "html_entity": "&#x20AC;",
            "iso_code": "EUR",
            "iso_numeric": "978",
            "name": "Euro",
            "priority": 2,
            "smallest_denomination": 1,
            "subunit": "Cent",
            "subunit_to_unit": 100,
            "symbol": "€",
            "symbol_first": true,
            "thousands_separator": "."
        },
```

this is Money::Currency.table

```
"aed": {
            "priority": 100,
            "iso_code": "AED",
            "name": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
            "symbol": "د.إ",
            "alternate_symbols": [
                "DH",
                "Dhs"
            ],
            "subunit": "Fils",
            "subunit_to_unit": 100,
            "symbol_first": false,
            "html_entity": "",
            "decimal_mark": ".",
            "thousands_separator": ",",
            "iso_numeric": "784",
            "smallest_denomination": 25
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with money-6.6.1 (the one I currently use). Probably works for the newer versions too.

```
Money::Currency.all.map { |m| [m.iso_code, m.name] } # => [["USD", "United States Dollar"], ...]

Money::Currency.table.values.map { |m| [m[:iso_code], m[:name]] }
# or
Money::Currency.table.values.map { |m| [m["iso_code"], m["name"]] }
```

Comment: If this helped please consider accepting the answer and vote up. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pluck` to directly get values from an ActiveRecord Collection

In your case you can do

```rb
Money::Currency.all.pluck(:iso_code, :name)
```

You can read more about `pluck` from [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

Comment: Money::Currency is not a ActiveRecord model, it comes from the money gem.

Comment: Did you mention that anywhere?. Why have you posted with rails tag if it's not an rails code. Please phrase your question property